# Why does text <h1> shift the placement of my divs?

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

My h1 tag shifts the entire div down when I have 2 or more divs next to each other enclosed in another div.
How do I make it so that I can add my text without the divs shifting.
I tried to add text onto a single div enclosed by another div and it only seems to be wrong when there are 2 or more divs next to each other inside a div. Any help is appreciated. [This is how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amUMp.jpg) but
[This is how I want it to look but with the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73BHA.png)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <title>Document</title>
            <link href="positioningTrial.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="seperate">
                <div class="inside">
                    <h1>hello</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="inside">
                 
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <!--   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
            <div id="main-cont">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>hello</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="middle"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="middle"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="middle"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    h1,
    p {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #seperate {
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 10vw;
        width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .inside {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 40%;
    }
    /*  ----------------------------------------------  */
    #main-cont {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        border: 3px solid blue;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .row {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
        border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    }
    .left,
    .middle,
    .right {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
    .left {
    }
    .middle {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .right {
    }
    
    /* --------------------------------------------- */


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGHtm.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some crossed wires with how the page layout works.

Can you make a simplified version in jsFiddle like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/hupdmg3q/ or something?

It's hard to tell what you want to happen from the image you provide.

> How do I make it so that I can add my text without the divs shifting

All of the block-level elements are just full-width boxes:

```
<header>
  <h1>Heading example</h1>
  
  <div>Example div</div>
</header>
```

So, their existence takes up space - and pushes each other down the page.

Your CSS looks like you are kinda fighting the nature of how the pages work.

Here's some other things to think about: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/7j3f2chw/

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion for future questions, how I want it to look is for all the boxes to be contained in the wider div. In the picture attached, only 2 of the boxes are out of place and those are the ones that contains the text. So my question is how can I add the text but also make it so that the box does not jump out of the div that it is contained in. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the footer in that example jsFiddle I included. It's to children in a parent: next to each other. But - I'm not really sure if that helps you. Also see: https://dev.to/perpetual_education/almost-all-of-the-ui-comes-down-to-just-this-24ef

Comment: on another note: check out: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Basically: setting any explicit heights is going to come back to haunt you. The page will stretch based on its content. In your case, you are setting the height often - and sometimes to 100%, but 100% of what? You also shouldn't be using inline-block the way you are using it there.